# Is listening to an empty rmq queue network intensive?

Tags: networking, rabbitmq, amqp

In a microservice system I have two services: **service1** which has a piece of data and **service2** which needs that up to date data from time to time. In order to get the status, **service2** calls service 1 through HTTP calls.

*service2 --- (get data call) ---> service1*

Since **service1** changes data status once a couple of hours, I am thinking that in order to lift some load from the network I can replace the constant polling through HTTP calls by a RabbitMQ message being sent from **service1** to **service2** and that **service2** can cache that till the next message is received.

*service1 --- (rmq message sent) ---> service2*

Considering that the HTTP requests are currently made once per ~10 seconds, and that the data is updated once a few hours, will it be easier from a network point of view to support the new design? In other words, **how network intensive is listening on an empty RMQ queue? Is it less intensive than sending an HTTP GET call once each 10 seconds?**

Comment: Note: even though it may sound silly to care about traffic for this simplified scenario, I will be scaling this model to at least a dozen services which will translate in millions of requests on a daily basis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how network intensive is listening on an empty RMQ queue? Is it less intensive than sending an HTTP GET call once each 10 seconds?

Yes, it is less "intensive". By "intensive" I assume you mean the bandwidth consumed.

A RabbitMQ consumer will still send heartbeat messages on occasion.

To be honest the biggest improvement will be moving away from a polling architecture to one that is push-based.

Answer (score 0):

It is not network intensive to listen to an empty RabbitMQ queue. The messages are pushed by RabbitMQ to a subscriber of the queue, so communication only happens when a new message appears on the queue.